# Delete records in ActiveRecord_Relation when duplicate rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ActiveRecord_Relation

[image]

I want result

[image]

help me!!!
Thanks so much

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the duplicates?

Comment: Suggest types the code from the image in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use**

```
validates_uniqueness_of
```

default validation of **ruby** model and restrict from saving duplicate data.

This validation apply on **More than 1 column**

***Answer***

```
validates_uniqueness_of :id, :template, uniqueness: true, scope: [:template,:id]
```

Even you don't need to Add custom messages for that, ruby and rails give it automatically when the validation is fired.

[Click Here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) for more inforamtion

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can use Ruby's `uniq` to remove the duplicate records from your relation

(2) If you don't want duplicate data in database, use a unique constraint

(3) If you want a faster solution than (1), look into "SELECT DISTINCT by column"

Hope this helps.